# How do I install Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

How do I install Bluetooth on my computer? My camera has no facility for wire or cable transfer only Bluetooth.
Thank you.

Comment: what ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: It should work out of the box. Please edit the question with the make and model of the bluetooth device if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you will find a documentary about installing bluetooth here :

[Bluetooth installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your computer needs to be capable of using Bluetooth. You need a device either build in or as an external stick or something that allows your computer to communicate via Bluetooth. In case you have a device all the required packages should be installed by default.

This is how the bluetooth indicator looks in Ubuntu 12.04:

[image: The bluetooth icon is the one to the left.]

The icon to the left is the bluetooth indicator. If the packages are not installed you can use the [official installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup).